# Convert Tkinter py file into EXE file using windows power shell

Tags: python, powershell, tkinter

I am trying to convert my `tkinter` python file into `.exe` using windows power shell. But i am getting below error.

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

**My source code .**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import rcParams
# figure size in inches
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 5,6
root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
def open_file():
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Excel Files', '*.xlsx')])
    print(file)
    print(type(file))
    print(file.name)
    
    data=pd.read_excel(file.name)
    print(pd.crosstab(data["Sex"],data.Survived))
    ax = sns.countplot(x = 'Sex', hue = 'Survived', palette = 'Set1', data = data)
    ax.set(title = 'Total Survivors According to Sex', xlabel = 'Sex', ylabel='Total')
    plt.show()
    wb = load_workbook(filename = file.name,read_only=True) # Load into openpyxl
    wb2 = wb.active
    #Whatever you want to do with the WorkSheet
btn = Button(root, text ='Open excel sheet', command = open_file)
btn.pack(side='top')
#btn.pack(side='bottom')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with PowerShell?

Comment: @Theo It does (title) but it seems like it is a code request therefore off-topic

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need to convert your Python file to EXE. if so, there are lots of libraries available to convert your python file to EXE file. one best i use is PyInstaller. You can try that. Refer this link for more : https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

Comment: I refereed that site but i am getting  "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded " would you plz convert above python into .exe file in windows power shell

Comment: Please visit this site for how to set recursion limit : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-handling-recursion-limit/